# Filter duplicates array elements and merge into one array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter duplicates from array of array elements into a single array removing duplicates.

Below is the snippet

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3]
]

const result = arr.map((res) => [...new Set(res)]);

console.log(result)
```

The expected output is `[1,2,3]`. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arr.flat() instead like this

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2, 3]
]

const result = [...new Set(arr.flat())];

console.log(result)
```